# How to declare i18next in React App.tsx only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next

I want to declare `const { t } = useTranslation()` in React App.tsx only. And then I want to use `{ t(trans.things) }` without to declare `const { t } = useTranslation()` in my components.

Is there any way to do the above without the lint error when using 'no-unused-vars' in eslint?

Comment: I see! have a look at this example maybe it can help you :) https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-night-yp181k?file=/src/app.js

Comment: @MilanSachani Thank you! But I want to declare it in root component only. Like vue. But in React, this seems to have to be declared for each component.

Comment: I see sure I will try to find an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always just access the t function of the i18next instance (i18next.t)
Like shown in this i18next course: https://youtu.be/SA_9i4TtxLQ

Comment: It's very nice vedio! thank you! @adrai